# How do I order a list in MySQL so that a specific id always shows up first?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

MySQL

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+
```

How do I order this list, so that 2 always shows up first? It should output 2, 1, 3, 4, and not 1, 2, 3, 4. Or I could also pick 3 to show up first, so it would output 3, 1, 2, 4.

PHP

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ???");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN 0 ELSE ID END
```

Comment: This accomplishes the same thing as my example, but is obviously more complex.  Is this more widely supported across database types, or is there a compelling reason to use the more complex syntax?  I have to admit I am not familiar with this method, and am interested to know the value in the more verbose route.

Comment: @Chris - as lucho points out, your example is dependent on the order of insertion (or the default ordering for the table).  In his example it MAY work, but it would not work in the general case.

Answer (score 3):

I use this trick:

```
SELECT
   IF (`id` = 2, -1, `id`) AS `weight`
FROM `table` ORDER BY `weight` ASC;
```

I like Chris' answer, It's the best method for sure! (You learn something every day)

Comment: +1 - a less verbose version of my answer, and I believe you can put the `IF` statement right in the `ORDER BY` clause without having to actually add a column for it.

Comment: +1 - thanks for your comment on my answer, but it looks like YOU'VE got the better way! :)

Answer (score 0):

Another trick is to use field() function

```
select * from table order by field(2,id) desc,id
```